# SAML Provider/Implementations Compatible?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth, pingfederate

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this subject for me.  I have two customers that want to integration with my software as a service (SaaS) application using SAML Single Sign-On.

- Customer A is using [PingFederate](https://www.pingidentity.com/products/pingfederate/) as their Identity Provider
- Customer B is using [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.net/) as their Identity Provider

I'm wondering, if I set up the Service Provider instance of either one of these two solutions, can the interoperate with the other since they both use SAML?

For example:

[Customer] PingFederate --> [ServiceProvider] Shibboleth

OR

[Customer] Shibboleth --> [ServiceProvider] PingFederate

Answer (score 2):

That's essentially the point of having a SAML standard.  What you use to implement the service provider and what they use to implement the identity provider shouldn't matter, as long as both sides are following the standard.